# NSIndexPath warnings in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, nsindexpath

I am getting a warning while creating the NSIndexPath,

```
NSInteger arr[] = {0,3};
[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:arr length:2]
```

`warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'indexPathWithIndexes:length:' differ in signedness`

What is the warning due to ?? How to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have the array be of type `NSUInteger` (unsigned).

It's telling you that because NSIndexPath does NOT want negative values, which you could potentially be passing in via an NSInteger array (really an int).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're developing for the iPhone, you should use the UIKit additions intended for creating index paths to represent positions in `UITableViews`. You should construct your example like so: `NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:3];` See [this Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSIndexPath/indexPathForRow:inSection:) for more information.